# Can't center duplicate picture

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, computer-vision, centering

So for this code to work properly, i need it to center the new image in the black space with borders around it. I've been trying to take the first image dimensions and subtract the new enlarged empty dimensions but I can't seem to get it to work. I'm not sure what to do at this point. I've managed to duplicate the picture i just need to center it now.

````
import numpy as np
# read in image (in the same folder)
image = cv2.imread("cones11.png")
# get size of image
numRows = image.shape[0] # height of image
numCols = image.shape[1] # width of image
print(image.shape[0])
print(image.shape[1])
#scalar
scalar = 1.2
#newdimensions nxn
n = int (scalar * numRows)
n1 = int(scalar * numCols)

shift = n/2
shift1 = n1/2

# create an empty color image
emptyIm = np.zeros((n, n1, 3))  # (size, data type)

# iterate over all the pixels of your image
for i in range(numRows): # iterate over height of image, y-coordinates
    for j in range(numCols): # iteratve over the width of image, x-coordinates
        # access values at a pixel:
        # image[i][j][0]: blue value stored at pixel (i,j)
        # image[i][j][1]: green value stored at pixel (i,j)
        # image[i][j][2]: red value stored at pixel (i,j)
        #image[i][j][0] = emptyIm[i][j][0]
        #image[i][j][1] = emptyIm[i][j][1]
        #image[i][j][2] = emptyIm[i][j][2]
        emptyIm[i,j] = emptyIm[j,i] - image[int(shift)-1, int(shift1)-1]
        emptyIm[i][j][0] = image[i][j][0]
        emptyIm[i][j][1] = image[i][j][1]
        emptyIm[i][j][2] = image[i][j][2]


#emptyIm[i][j] = emptyIm[i+n][i+n]
#enlarging image
# n = 2*emptyIm[i][j]
cv2.imshow("xd", image)
cv2.imshow("enlarged", emptyIm/255.0)
cv2.waitKey(0)```
````

Comment: debug it. look at variables. post some numbers. your code contains numbers. they are important.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.